# JSF loading large results in single page

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, rendering

We have requirement to load JSF page with more columns(90+columns) and around 1000 records in single page with column freeze feature. Scrollable data table had performance issue . What will be best way to achive it without performance issue?

Comment: You want all the 1000 records to show up on the same page at page load ?

Comment: Yes that is the requirement from customer and even he is not agreeing for Pagination . Currently we are showing only 100 records with pagination but because of number of columns and freezing feature it is also slower.